# Resume download with pySmartDL

Tags: python, download, pysmartdl

I would like to know if, when the program stops while downloading a file with pySmartDL, it is possible to resume it where it stopped

Answer (score 0):

is pause/unpause what you are looking for?
https://github.com/iTaybb/pySmartDL/blob/master/test/test_pySmartDL.py#L76

```
    def test_pause_unpause(self, testfile=None):
        obj = pySmartDL.SmartDL(testfile if testfile else self.res_7za920_mirrors, dest=self.dl_dir, progress_bar=False, connect_default_logger=self.enable_logging)
        obj.start(blocking=False)
        
        while not obj.get_dl_size():
            time.sleep(0.1)
        
        # pause
        obj.pause()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if obj.get_status() == "finished":
            # too bad, the file was too small and was downloaded complectely until we stopped it.
            # We should download a bigger file
            if self.res_testfile_100mb == testfile:
                self.fail("The download got completed before we could stop it, even though we've used a big file. Are we on a 100GB/s internet connection or somethin'?")
            return self.test_pause_unpause(testfile=self.res_testfile_100mb)
        
        dl_size = obj.get_dl_size()

        # verify download has really stopped
        time.sleep(2.5)
        self.assertEqual(dl_size, obj.get_dl_size())
        
        # continue
        obj.unpause()
        time.sleep(2.5)
        self.assertNotEqual(dl_size, obj.get_dl_size())
        
        obj.wait()
        self.assertTrue(obj.isSuccessful())
```

more likely you want restart partially downloaded file which has this issue opened. https://github.com/iTaybb/pySmartDL/issues/14